# How to preserve pytorch training on AWS after ssh disconnection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, tmux

I am currently connecting to Amazon AWS EC2 through ssh, and I use it to train a pytorch network.

The problem is that whenever the local ssh terminal window is closed, training is interrupted on AWS. And if I connect again, there are no processes running on AWS.

How can I keep the network training on AWS all the time, such that if I close the ssh terminal window, I can still connect again and find the network training?

**Update:**

Running `python main.py &` does not work. If I close the ssh window and connect again and run `top` I find no processes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a terminal multiplexer like [**tmux**](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) or [**screen**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man4/screen.4freebsd.html). 
This way you can detach from your screen without killing the running process.

For instance with **tmux**. A few things to get started, running `tmux` will create a new session. <kbd>Ctrl B-D</kbd> to detach the view; `tmux a` to access the last session, <kbd>Ctrl B-S</kbd> to list the live sessions.